# Application URL redirecting to 'ParentDirectory' page by default

Tags: angular

I hosted an ANgular app on IIS server. My web config entry has Rewrite url = "/MapInternal" however the url opens the parent Directory instead of Index.html .

Can someone please help what I am missing here?

```
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/MapInternal" />
<!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
```

I am expecting my https://servername/Mapinternal opens indexs.html by default instead of 'Parent Directory'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI9vc.png)

Also when I browse my url 'https://servername/Mapinternal/index.html' site opens and url auto resolves to 'https://servername/Mapinternal'. However when I try https://servername/Mapinternal' it opens Parent directory